# OpenFeint + iPad + Hiding status bar

Tags: ipad, statusbar, openfeint

My app runs fullscreen no status bar but when OF starts and asks for which account to use, a status bar appears.

How can I disable this? Note that when the OF connection window closes it leaves a white rectangle in place of the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the viewController from window, set the size required and add it again to window. Sample code is as follows:

```
- (void)dashboardWillDisappear
{
    _appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [_appDelegate.navcontroller.view removeFromSuperview];
    [_appDelegate.window setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 1024.0)];
    [_appDelegate.window addSubview:_appDelegate.navcontroller.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I was missing something but here is how I fixed it.
In my OF delegate implementation if added this:

```
- (void)dashboardDidDisappear
{
   MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

   [[[appDelegate viewController] view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH)];
}
```

having defined SCREEN_WIDTH and SCREEN_HEIGHT accordingly...

I hope this will help...